# fifo underrun error shown during booting

Tags: boot, drm

Following errors are shown every time i boot my ubuntu:

[drm:cpt_set_fifo_underrun_reporting] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

It would be great help if someone can tell me why its coming and how to solve it.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're running into this bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261

It doesn't seem to be much of an issue, as only one person on the list mentioned seeing any problems besides the pair of errors in the logs.