# Pipe B FIFO underrun

Tags: 14.04, xorg

All of a sudden, while reading my mail, I got this:

[image]

What does it mean and how to avoid it? I do not use Nvidia or any other proprietary drivers.

I could `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and kill X as a workaround, which let me relogin, however, I obviously lost my X session with the open apps.

Ironically, there is a similar question here on SO where [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/587807/149354) says "It doesn't seem to be much of an issue". Well, it is for me.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in the latest releases of kernel (>=4.1)

Comment: I cannot upgrade to Vivid and the packages for 4.1 are only available as RC for Vivid (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1-rc2-vivid/). I'm afraid it will introduce more bugs than help. Are you aware of a patch or an accepted bug report?