# System doesn't boot upon upgrade to 15.10

Tags: startup, 15.10, boot

[image]

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04, and I haven't been able to use my computer. I am getting desperate. Is there a way to fix this or to revert to the old version.

Find attached an image of the error.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, and has been reported before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/582299/fifo-underrun-error-shown-during-booting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 at this point?

Also try booting in Recovery Mode and if still possible trying booting from the old 15.04 kernel, as I had two options for each kernerl after I upgraded.

It may be possible to 're-install' Ubuntu 15.10 using the LiveCD to fix any broken packages from the upgrade without losing your files and programs, but I don't think this is possible for a 15.10 > 15.04. (Correct me if i'm wrong though).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried the ctrl + alt + f2 and I was able to log in, but there is no graphical user interface. It just logs me into the command line. please I'd appreciate any further help